# Sum function has unexpected behavior

Tags: python, sum

I have a problem using the `sum()` function within my defined function. When I write the same code without defining a function everything works.

```
new_game = input("Do you want to play a game of Blackjack? Type 'y' or 'n': \n")

while new_game == 'y':
  my_cards = []
  computer_cards = []
  cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
  # Dodaj 2 karty do każdej listy
  my_cards += random.sample(cards, 2)
  computer_cards += random.sample(cards, 2)
  my_score = 0
  computer_score = 0

  
  def sum_scores():
    my_score = sum(my_cards)
    return my_score
    computer_score = sum(computer_cards)
    return computer_score
    
    if my_score > 21:
      if 11 in my_cards:
        my_score = my_score - 10
        return my_score
    if computer_score > 21:
      if 11 in computer_cards:
        computer_score = computer_score - 10
        return computer_score
   
  sum_scores()
  print(f"Your cards: {my_cards}, current score: {my_score} ")
  print(f"Computer first card: {computer_cards[0]}")
  continue_game = input("Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass.")
  if continue_game == "n":
    break
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, what do you think `return` means in a Python program? When `return` is reached, what happens to the execution of the function? Next - how did you learn about writing functions in the first place? Please go back and re-read it.

Comment: Welcome! It is helpful when asking a question here to describe what you expect the output to be, and what the output actually is. 'This doesn't work' doesn't let us know in what way it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function can only `return` once.  As soon as your function gets to its first `return` statement, it's done:

```
  def sum_scores():
    my_score = sum(my_cards)
    return my_score
    # all done!
```

Instead, wait until you're all done computing the two scores before you return them:

```
  def sum_scores(my_cards, computer_cards):
    my_score = sum(my_cards)
    computer_score = sum(computer_cards)
    
    if my_score > 21 and 11 in my_cards:
      my_score -= 10
    if computer_score > 21 and 11 in computer_cards:
      computer_score -= 10

    return my_score, computer_score
```

and then when you call `sum_scores()`, make sure to assign the return values to variables so you can use them outside the function:

```
  my_score, computer_score = sum_scores(my_cards, computer_cards)
  print(f"Your cards: {my_cards}, current score: {my_score} ")
```